# LINUX : How to share files from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 10.4 with VirtualBox?

Tags: windows, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, file-transfer

How to share files across Parent Operating system `Windows 7` and Virtual Operating System `Ubuntu Linux 10.4`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select Devices>>Shared Folders when you pull up the virtual machine.  There is an option to setup a link of files between the two.

[image]